# Sorting Python list based on the length of the string

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort a list of strings based on the string length. I tried to use sort as follows, but it doesn't seem to give me correct result.

```
xs = ['dddd','a','bb','ccc']
print xs
xs.sort(lambda x,y: len(x) < len(y))
print xs

['dddd', 'a', 'bb', 'ccc']
['dddd', 'a', 'bb', 'ccc']
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 266, accepted):

When you pass a `lambda` to `sort`, you need to return an integer, not a boolean.  So your code should instead read as follows:

```
xs.sort(lambda x,y: cmp(len(x), len(y)))
```

Note that [cmp](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#cmp) is a builtin function such that `cmp(x, y)` returns -1 if `x` is less than `y`, 0 if `x` is equal to `y`, and 1 if `x` is greater than `y`.

Of course, you can instead use the `key` parameter:

```
xs.sort(key=lambda s: len(s))
```

This tells the `sort` method to order based on whatever the key function returns.

EDIT: Thanks to balpha and Ruslan below for pointing out that you can just pass `len` directly as the key parameter to the function, thus eliminating the need for a `lambda`:

```
xs.sort(key=len)
```

And as Ruslan points out below, you can also use the built-in [sorted](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) function rather than the `list.sort` method, which creates a new list rather than sorting the existing one in-place:

```
print(sorted(xs, key=len))
```

Comment: No need for the `lambda`; just use `key = len`

Comment: This will sort in Ascending Order(Smaller length of words at top), to sort in Descending Order(Smaller Length of words at bottom) add a parameter **reverse=True**

Comment: The `xs.sort()` throws "TypeError: sort() takes no positional arguments". Instead it should be `xs.sort(key=lambda x: len(x))`

Answer (score 118):

The same as in Eli's answer - just using a shorter form, because you can skip a `lambda` part here.

Creating new list:

```
>>> xs = ['dddd','a','bb','ccc']
>>> sorted(xs, key=len)
['a', 'bb', 'ccc', 'dddd']
```

In-place sorting:

```
>>> xs.sort(key=len)
>>> xs
['a', 'bb', 'ccc', 'dddd']
```

Comment: How do I reverse sort on length?

Comment: @user2922935 : You can do xs[::-1] to reverse the already sorted list.
Check out Dan Bader's article here : https://dbader.org/blog/python-reverse-list

Comment: `xs.sort(key=len, reverse=True)`

Answer (score 9):

**The easiest way to do this is:**

> list.sort(key = lambda x:len(x))

Answer (score 5):

I Would like to add how the pythonic key function works while sorting :

**Decorate-Sort-Undecorate Design Pattern :**

Python’s support for a key function when sorting is implemented using what is known as the 
decorate-sort-undecorate design pattern.

**It proceeds in 3 steps:**

1. Each element of the list is temporarily replaced with a “decorated” version that includes the result of the key function applied to the element.
2. The list is sorted based upon the natural order of the keys.
3. The decorated elements are replaced by the original elements.

Key parameter to specify a function to be called on each list element prior to making comparisons. [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html)

Answer (score 2):

Write a function lensort to sort a list of strings based on length.

```
def lensort(a):
    n = len(a)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            if len(a[i]) > len(a[j]):
                temp = a[i]
                a[i] = a[j]
                a[j] = temp
    return a
print lensort(["hello","bye","good"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I can do it using below two methods, using function

```
def lensort(x):
    list1 = []
    for i in x:
        list1.append([len(i),i])
    return sorted(list1)

lista = ['a', 'bb', 'ccc', 'dddd']
a=lensort(lista)
print([l[1] for l in a])
```

In one Liner  using Lambda, as below, a already answered above.

```
 lista = ['a', 'bb', 'ccc', 'dddd']
 lista.sort(key = lambda x:len(x))
 print(lista)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def lensort(list_1):
    list_2=[];list_3=[]
for i in list_1:
    list_2.append([i,len(i)])
list_2.sort(key = lambda x : x[1])
for i in list_2:
    list_3.append(i[0])
return list_3
```

This works for me!

Answer (score -1):

```py
def swap_pos(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in range(0, i):
            if len(lst[j]) < len(lst[i]):
                lst.insert(j, lst[i])
                lst.pop(i + 1)
                break

    print(lst)

swap_pos(technology)
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers; instead, explain ***why*** your answer works. See [answer] for more information on how to write a good answer.