# outputting a list in order of shortest word to longest word (python)

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to sort by length of string followed by alphabetical order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659524/how-to-sort-by-length-of-string-followed-by-alphabetical-order)

I want to create a program that prints the word in a list in order of shortest to longest character count. For example:

```
["My", "turtle", "is", "old"]
```

would output:

```
"My"
"is"
"old"
"turtle"
```

Is there any simple way to do this? I have so far:

```
message = "My turtle is old"
message = message.split(" ")
```

Comment: How is that at all representative of "in order of longest to shortest character count"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to sort by length of string followed by alphabetical order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659524/how-to-sort-by-length-of-string-followed-by-alphabetical-order) and even more exact [Sorting Python list based on the length of the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587402/sorting-python-list-based-on-the-length-of-the-string) which I found by googling "python sort by length".

Comment: How come the title is shortest to longest and the question is from longest to shortest ? Make up your mind :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l = ["My", "turtle", "is", "old"]
l.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
# -> ['turtle', 'old', 'My', 'is']
```

You might wish to review the Python wiki on the subject: http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Comment: Try it without `reverse=True`.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the input by length using the `key` keyword for `.sort()`:

```
l = ["My", "turtle", "is", "old"]
l.sort(key=len)

for i in l:
  print i
```