# How can I return the name of the states based on population from the list?

Tags: python, list, function, sorting

I am new to python and working on a small project

```
NE = [ ("Maine", 30840, 1.329), ("Vermont", 9217, .626), ("New Hampshire", 8953,1.321), ("Massachusetts", 7800, 6.646), ("Connecticut", 4842, 3.59), ("Rhode Island", 1044, 1.05)]
```

## where[0] is a state,[1] is land area,[2] is population

I have written the below code to sort in descending order of population

```
def s_sort(state):
    return state[2]

s_state = sorted(NE,key=s_sort,reverse=True)
print(s_state)
```

Output:

```
[('Vermont', 9217, 0.626), ('Rhode Island', 1044, 1.05), ('New Hampshire', 8953, 1.321), ('Maine', 30840, 1.329), ('Connecticut', 4842, 3.59), ('Massachusetts', 7800, 6.646)]
```

But how do I only return the name of the states from the above output in the same descending order within this function?

## My desired output:

```
Vermont,Rhode Island,New Hampshire,Maine,Connecticut,Massachusetts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension :

```
print([el[0] for el in s_state])
```

`["Vermont", "Rhode Island", "New Hampshire", "Maine", "Connecticut", "Massachusetts"]`

[More on list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

(Or, yes, you can use the `map` built-in, as Malvolio suggests.)

Comment: How can I sort the list based on length of the name of state?

Comment: @user9991165 You can check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587402/sorting-python-list-based-on-the-length-of-the-string

Answer (score 1):

You need to 'pluck' the first valueout of every tuple in the list you have.  Python lacks an explicit `pluck` function, but you can use `map`.

```
st_state = map(lambda s: s[0], s_state)
```

(Or, yes, you can use a comprehension, as Fukiyel suggests.)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line of code will do the trick

```
s = [i[0] for i in s_state]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
state_names = []
for state in s_state:
    state_names.append(state[0])
return state_names
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer, as code only answers do  not always help learners. Please use the [edit] button to improve this answer.