# Count higher repetition streak

Tags: python

I've been given this string:

```
'V--V----V--P--VV---V------V--P--V--V'
```

I need to define a function that counts the longest streak of '-' in order to find the cost of making a fence.
In the case given, it would be *6*.

```
def cost(wall): #calculate the cost of building a wall with fences. the cost will be the longest streak of fences*10
    fence_count = 0
    streak = 0
    for fence in wall:
        if fence == '-':
            fence_count += 1
        elif fence == fence+1:
            fence_count += 1
        else:
            streak = fence_count
            fence_count = 0
    return streak*10
                    
wall = input()
c = cost(wall)
print(c)
```

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Is there a built-in function in Python that can do this?

Comment: Can you share what's you've tried?  and where got `error` or stuck?

Comment: Do P and V mean anything to you?

Comment: If you're a beginner, I'd say don't look at the answers you got. Fix that error, and add what you're missing instead of copy-pasting the solutions. That exception is because you're doing `fence+1` and `fence` is a string (well, a character). So you need to loop over index, not over elements. Also, you're not keeping track of which streak value is the max.

Comment: @ChatterOne exactly. It took me some time to explain the issue in my answer. The max-question is commented but not solved yet. Maybe shifting up the `streak` assignment  statement by some lines may be enough.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue

I commented and fixed your code to some extend:

```
fence_count = 0  # the count can only increase
streak = 0  # direct factor on costs (a fence streak of 1 costs 10)

# count fences (denoted by hyphen char '-')
# iterate through all chars (here variable fence) in a string (here wall)
for fence in wall:
    if fence == '-':  # if fence then increase counter
       fence_count += 1
    # What if fence_count is now higher than the previous streak ?
    elif fence_count > streak:
        # then we have a new maximum as (new) longest streak
    else:  # else restart counting (e.g. if 'V' or 'P') 
        streak = fence_count  # save counter as streak (only if longer than any streak before?)
        fence_count = 0  # reset counter

    # the longest streak was found
    return streak*10
```

You cannot add or concatenate (using `+` operator) a character (of type `str`) in `fence` to a number (of type `int`) in numerical literal `1`.

Thus the runtime-error

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

here:

```
    elif fence == fence+1:  # error raised here
       fence_count += 1
```

What should the increase and comparison do here?

#### Alternative solution using regex-split

Using a regex-split, then sort by length descending and finally printing the first (which is the max streak):

```
import re

line = 'V--V----V--P--VV---V------V--P--V--V'

segments = re.split('[^-]', line)  # split by all non-hyphen chars like V or P
print(segments)  # print the resulting 12 streaks (some empty)
# ['', '--', '----', '--', '--', '', '---', '------', '--', '--', '--', '']

segments.sort(key=lambda s: len(s), reverse=True)  # sorts in-place by length descending
print(segments)  # the longest at first after sorting
# ['------', '----', '---', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '', '', '']
print(len(segments[0]))  # print the length of the longest streak
# 6
```

See also:

- Python docs: [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)
- [Sorting Python list based on the length of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587402/sorting-python-list-based-on-the-length-of-the-string)

Comment: Can also try to shift the `elif fence_count > streak:` condition down into the else-block to make the (max) streak-assignment conditional. Of course you need to remove "el" then and indent the streak-assignment ️

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max()` with a `map()` function that counts the length of each run of dashes:

```py
from itertools import groupby
max(map(lambda x:sum(1 for c in x[1]) if x[0] == '-' else 0, groupby(data)))
```

This outputs:

```py
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), find all substrings that match `-+` (i.e. one or more `-`), `map` those to their `len` and get the `max`:

```
>>> line = 'V--V----V--P--VV---V------V--P--V--V'
>>> max(map(len, re.findall("-+", line)))
6
```