# How can I get this kind of dropdown with Qt? (Specifically PyQt4)

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

This is the type of dropdown window I would like.  It has columns, with different types of data in each.  I tried just using tab delimiting, but it made it look sloppy. How could I get a dropdown / combobox element like this using PyQt4?  (Ignore the black box, I just wanted to hide my system files).

[image: Columned Dropdown]

Answer (score 2):

By using your own custom item delegate. Probably not easy answer one would hope for, but you will have complete control :)

See http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/model-view-delegate.html

Comment: I was hoping for something a little more than this... But if I don't get any other answers I'll give you the bounty...

Answer (score 1):

I've not used PyQt, but if it's anything like PyGTK, it's possible to use something like [the tree widget.](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/qtreewidget.html)

Although as an alternative, you could simply use string formatting (much better than tab delimiting):

(new style formatting)

```
'{0:20}{0:20}'.format('l','lines in current document')
```

And if you want to make sure there's enough for each of the largest you could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873327/pythons-most-efficient-way-to-choose-longest-string-in-list):

```
leftwidth = len(max(['l', 'foo', 'longitem'], key=len))
rightwidth = len(max(['Number of lines', 
                      'some other option', 
                      'yet another long option'], key=len))

'{key:{L}}{desc:{R}}'.format(key='l',desc='Number of lines',
                             L=leftwidth, R=rightwidth)
```

And if you store your key/description in a dictionary it's even easier to automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, u must use QColumnView, it is extended version of Listview or just multiple listview. As you know, listview is opened version of Combobox.