# Length of the longest sublist?

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Python’s most efficient way to choose longest string in list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873327/pythons-most-efficient-way-to-choose-longest-string-in-list)

I have a list L

```
L = [[1,2,3],[5,7],[1,3],[77]]
```

I want to return the length of the longest sublist without needing to loop through them, in this case 3 because [1,2,3] is length 3 and it is the longest of the four sublists. I tried len(max(L)) but this doesn't do what I want. Any way to do this or is a loop my only way?

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/873327/1180720

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`max(L,key=len)` will give you the object with the longest length (`[1,2,3]` in your example) -- To actually get the length (if that's all you care about), you can do `len(max(L,key=len))` which is a bit ugly -- I'd break it up onto 2 lines.  Or you can use the version supplied by ecatamur.

All of these answers have loops -- in my case, the loops are *implicit* which usually means they'll be executed in optimized native machine code.  If you think about it, How could you know which element is the longest without looking at each one?

---

Finally, note that `key=function` isn't a feature that is specific to `max`.  A lot of the python builtins (`max`,`min`,`sorted`,`itertools.groupby`,...) use this particular keyword argument.  It's definitely worth investing a little time to understand how it works and what it typically does.

Comment: How does that work? Ah ok so there's no way to avoid it? Alright -- thanks!

Comment: @IAmBatman Did you read the documentation of `max`? Are you aware that functions are first class-values (which means, among other things, that they can be passed to other functions as arguments)?

Comment: @IAmBatman -- `max` applies the `key` function to each element of your list and picks the one where the `key` function returned the biggest.

Comment: @delnan I know that functions can be used as arguments, yes... I just don't have much experience using them in that way is all

Comment: @IAmBatman: Indeed you have to, if you wanted to know the largest length.

Answer (score 19):

Try a comprehension:

```
max(len(l) for l in L)
```

Comment: Using the `key` keyword is faster, I think.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Likely, seeing as it's in C (and PyPy has troubles optimizing generator expressions in some cases). But that's not why I'd recommend it. It's also clearer to me (but this is fine too, and I have noticed I lean more towards functional programming than many Python programmers).

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- There are very subtle differences.  `max(L,key=len)` gives the object with the biggest `len`, but it doesn't give you it's length :)

Comment: @mgilson: I just realized this as well. :-)