# Python - Returning longest strings from list

Tags: python

I have a list of strings like the one below:

```
stringList = ["a" , "aa", "aaa", "aaaa", "aaab", "aaac"]
```

What I am trying to do is return all the longest strings in the list, I have tried using the max function but it only returns one value, whereas in this case there are 3 strings with a length of 4.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: 1.find the length of longest string 2.filter the length equals that

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Maybe this? >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873327/pythons-most-efficient-way-to-choose-longest-string-in-list <<

Answer (score 8):

Use `list comprehension` and `max`:

```
>>> lis= ["a" , "aa", "aaa", "aaaa", "aaab", "aaac"]

>>> le = max(len(x) for x in lis)   #find out the max length      

>>> [x for x in lis if len(x) == le]  #now filter list based on that max length
['aaaa', 'aaab', 'aaac']
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe:

```
longest_len = 0
longest_strings = []

for s in stringList:
    if len(s) > longest_len:
        longest_len = len(s)
        longest_strings = [s]
    elif len(s) == longest_len:
        longest_strings.append(s)
```

Comment: This is definitively the fastest algorithm, not the most pythonic though..

Comment: It is not fastest. Too many wasted `append`s.

Comment: @BlaXpirit timeit and be surprised... double list traversal is 1.18 times slower at 100 elements and 1.22 times slower at 10000 elements. Strings generated by `sizes = [abs(int(random.gauss(20, 10)))+1 for _ in range(length)] ; stringList = [''.join(random.sample(longstring, s)) for s in sizes]`

Comment: If the list is already sorted by length, it's 1.25 times faster... but if you know the list is sorted you can just read the results from the end.

Answer (score 0):

A single list comprehension (even though the list is processed many times):

```
[s for s in stringList if len(s) == len(max(stringList, key=len))]
```

Since Python v2.5, min() and max() have an optional argument key that allows you to specify the comparison method.

Comment: The list is processed more than twice: the `if` is checked for every `s in stringList`, so `len(max(stringList, key=len))` is computed `len(stringList)` times.  It will show quadratic performance, more's the pity.

Comment: @DSM: you're right. I still have to get used to the interpreted nature of Python.