# Unexpected result from DataFrame.groupby() and max()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let say I have a CSV of name, gender, and its count.

I am looking for majority name by using groupby() and max(). But I found something strange from the result:

**CSV:**

```
Name     Gender  Count
Connie   F       90
Connie   F       78
Peter    M       200
Connie   M       5
Connie   F       94
Connie   F       67
John     M       100
Connie   F       73
Connie   F       82
Connie   F       73
May      F       65
```

**First part of the code is looking fine:**

```
>>>data = pd.read_csv('names.txt',names=['Name','Gender','Count'])
>>>data = data.groupby(['Name','Gender']).sum().reset_index()
>>>print (data)
     Name Gender  Count
0  Connie      F    557
1  Connie      M      5
2    John      M    100
3     May      F     65
4   Peter      M    200
```

**There are two records with 'Connie' and I need to select the majority one.**

```
>>>data= data.groupby(['Name']).max().reset_index()
>>>print(data)
     Name Gender  Count
0  Connie      M    557
1    John      M    100
2     May      F     65
3   Peter      M    200
```

Did I do something wrong so that the gender of 'Connie' is **M** instead of **F**? while the max count is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct, because `M` > `F`, better explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20463240/2901002).

Also I find [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2700#issuecomment-12346160), so `string` columns are not omitted by [automatic exclusion of nuisance columns](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns):

> strings have **lt()** defined so the built in min() and max() work on them. If the non-numeric object supports the proper comparison methods, min() and max() aggregate functions should be non-ambiguous.

```
print (data.groupby(['Name'])['Gender'].max())
Name
Connie    M
John      M
May       F
Peter     M
Name: Gender, dtype: object
```

For correct output need [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indices of max values per group in `Count` column and then select by `loc`:

```
print (data.groupby(['Name'])['Count'].idxmax())
Name
Connie    0
John      2
May       3
Peter     4
Name: Count, dtype: int64

data = data.loc[data.groupby(['Name'])['Count'].idxmax()]
print (data)
     Name Gender  Count
0  Connie      F    557
2    John      M    100
3     May      F     65
4   Peter      M    200
```