# Why is max() in pandas returning nan when there's no nan value in the column?

Tags: pandas, max, nan

The column is of type `str` with format like `2018-10-10`, and has no `nan` values.

```
print(df['col'].isna().sum()) # 0
print(df['col'].max()) # nan
```

`min()` on the other hand shows the correct value

```
print(df['col'].min()) # 2018-01-01
```

Why is `max()` reporting nan value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is at least one string `nan`, you can test it:

```
print (df[df['col'] == 'nan'])
```

`max` function in python/pandas working with strings also and returns the one that is at the bottom of the alphabetic list, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20463204/2901002).

Comment: you're right. How come `df['col'].isna().sum()` doesn't show it? Maybe because `nan` is not interpreted as `NaN`?

Comment: No, because `ìsna` testing only missing values, not strings `nan`s