# Can someone explain the output of the following code regarding max()?

Tags: python

Python code:

```
print(max(['2020','4','70','5']))
```

I am getting the output as `70`

I want to understand how `max()` works on strings.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: If you want to find the largest number in that list: `print([int(x) for x in your_list_here])`

Comment: `print(max(['2020','4','70','5'], key=int))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you provide `max()` a `string`, it returns the **highest alphabetical character in a string**. So it will order based on alphabetical order descending.

As explained here [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-max/#:~:text=os._exit()-,Python%20String%20%7C%20max(),alphabetical%20character%20in%20a%20string.&text=Return%20value%3A,highest%20character%20in%20the%20string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-max/#:%7E:text=os._exit()-,Python%20String%20%7C%20max(),alphabetical%20character%20in%20a%20string.&text=Return%20value%3A,highest%20character%20in%20the%20string).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463204/how-does-the-max-function-work-on-list-of-strings-in-python

Answer (score -1):

max() can be used in 2 ways

1. Finding the largest item in an iterable

```
max(iterable, *iterables, key, default)
```

2. Getting the largest number in a list

```
number = [3, 2, 8, 5, 10, 6]
largest_number = max(number);
```

I think that what you want is this last one. If you also added a

```
print(largest_number)
```

It would throw you the output of `10`.

Comment: Are you implying that `list` is **not** `iterable`?

Comment: No but in this case I think in this specific case he should even change `['2020','4','70','5']` to `[2020,4,70,5]` since he seems to be trying to print the largest number and doing so will fix the "error" he's getting

Comment: OPs problem is that she does not understand the difference between numeric value and its character representation and you answer does not help.

Comment: Seems clear to me but alright. It's literally there that for numbers, your best choice would be going with what I pointed as "2."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463204/how-does-the-max-function-work-on-list-of-strings-in-python

Comment: _I think that what you want is this last one._ You should make it clear that the difference is in the values (and their type), not how you use the function. It's a bit confusing.