# What is the result of max(l) when l is a list of strings in Python?

Tags: python

I'm a python beginner and I have a question. I defined:

```
s = 'Manchester united is the best football team'
l = s.split(' ')
max(l)
```

The final answer was `united`, but I expected it should have been `Manchester`, because: `len(l[0]) = 10` and `len(l[1]) = 6`.

Is there someone to answer my question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the max() function work on list of strings in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463204/how-does-the-max-function-work-on-list-of-strings-in-python)

Comment: max takes the last item sorted. So if you sort that list in alpha order, the max/last item will be `'united'`. Try `s = 'Manchester united is za best football team'`, and it will return `'za'`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This was already answered here stackoverflow.com/a/20463240/964862

Comment: Then maybe vote to close it as a duplicate?  This really isn't an answer.

Comment: Not sure how I can do that

Comment: Use the "flag --> duplicate link --> submit" sequence on the question.

Comment: Thank you, just flagged it.