# Finding length of the longest list in an irregular list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have to find the longest list inside a list of lists.

For example:

`longest([1,2,3])` returns 3

`longest([[[1,2,3]]])` also returns 3 (inner list is 3)

`longest([[], [3,[4,5],[2,3,4,5,3,3], [7], 5, [1,2,3], [3,4]], [1,2,3,4,5]])` returns 7 (list `[3,[4,5],[2,3,4,5,3,3], [7], 5, [1,2,3], [3,4]]` contains 7 elements)

Right now I have this code, but it doesn't do the trick with the first two examples.

```
def longest(list1):
    longest_list = max(len(elem) for elem in list1)
    return longest_list
```

Maybe recursion will help?

Comment: Is there a known maximum depth of lists, or do you need to keep that general?

Comment: you can check if an element of the parent list is a list with [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) - then you can check the length of that list recursively.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python's most efficient way to choose longest string in list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873327/pythons-most-efficient-way-to-choose-longest-string-in-list)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution for any depth list:

```
def longest(l):
    if not isinstance(l, list):
        return 0
    return max(
            [len(l)] 
            + [len(subl) for subl in l if isinstance(subl, list)] 
            + [longest(subl) for subl in l]
            )
```

Answer (score 27):

These simple few lines works for me, my list is a nested one (list of lists)

```
#define the function#
def find_max_list(list):
    list_len = [len(i) for i in list]
    print(max(list_len))

#print output#
find_max_list(your_list)
```

Comment: You have to explain little bit more

Comment: Nice. is it possible to get the element position of the longest list?

Comment: @ScipioAfricanus Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/62966642/1497720

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem, it won't work with several nested lists.

Answer (score 6):

Python 3.3 version:

```
def lengths(x):
    if isinstance(x,list):
        yield len(x)
        for y in x:
            yield from lengths(y)
```

usage:

```
>>> l = [[], [3,[4,5],[2,3,4,5,3,3], [7], 5, [1,2,3], [3,4]], [1,2,3,4,5]]
>>> max(lengths(l))
7
```

In python 2.6+ you don't have the `yield from` statement (was introduced in python 3.3), so you have to change the code slightly:

```
def lengths(x):
    if isinstance(x,list):
        yield len(x)
        for y in x:
            for z in lengths(y):
                yield z
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `enumerate`, `sorted` and behavior of `list`:

```
ll = [[10,20], [1,2,3,4,5], [7,8,9]]
longest = ll[sorted([(i,len(l)) for i,l in enumerate(ll)], key=lambda t: t[1])[-1][0]]

>>longest
>>[1,2,3,4,5]
```

**Explanation**

1. Create `list` of `tuple` with index as first element and `len(l)` (length of list) as second element:

   `[(i,len(l)) for i,l in enumerate(ll)]`

   `>>[(0, 2), (1, 5), (2, 3)]`
2. Sort above list by second element in tuple that tuple with longest length gets to the end of the list:

   `sorted([(i,len(l)) for i,l in enumerate(ll)], key=lambda t: t[1])`

   `>>[(0, 2), (2, 3), (1, 5)]`
3. Catch the last tuple and its first element:

   `sorted([(i,len(l)) for i,l in enumerate(ll)], key=lambda t: t[1])[-1][0]`

   `>>1`
4. Use above result as the index in `ll` to get the longest list:

   `ll[sorted([(i,len(l)) for i,l in enumerate(ll)], key=lambda t: t[1])[-1][0]]`

   `>>[1,2,3,4,5]`

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, recursion can solve this.

```
def longest(lst):
    if type(lst) is not list:
        return 0
    max = len(lst)
    for i in lst:
        max_i = longest(i)
        if max_i > max:
            max = max_i
    return max
```

Comment: It's just a matter of style, I enjoy having multiple return statements in a method. It's easy to spot the base case I guess.

Answer (score 2):

The following will give you the indices of longest link:

```
import numpy as np
def find_max_list_idx(list):
    list_len = [len(i) for i in list]
    return np.argmax(np.array(list_len))
```

Example

```
a=[[1],[1,2,3],[3,4]]
print(find_max_list_idx(a))

'''
it will print index 1 as output
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with recursion:

```
def longest(list1) :
    l = 0
    if type(list1) is list :
        l = len(list1)
        if l > 0 :
            l = max(l,max(longest(elem) for elem in list1))
    return l
```

[(online demo)](https://repl.it/tBX).

The code first checks if this `is list` we are dealing with. If so, we first take the `len` of the list. Next we perform a recursive call on its elements. And calculate the maximum `longest` of the elements. If the maximum is greater than the length itself. We return that maximum, otherwise we return the length.

Because the `longest` of a non-list is zero, the recursion will stop, and we have an answer for single elements to be used in the inductive step.

Answer (score 1):

Another recursive function using map:

```
def longest(a):
    return max(len(a), *map(longest, a)) if isinstance(a, list) and a else 0
```

---

```
In [2]:  longest([1,2,3])
Out[2]:  3

In [3]:  longest([[[1,2,3]]]) 
Out[3]:  3

In [4]:  longest([[], [3,[4,5],[2,3,4,5,3,3], [7], 5, [1,2,3], [3,4]], [1,2,3,4,5]])
Out[4]:  7
```

and iteratively:

```
def longest(a):
    mx = 0
    stack = [a[:]]
    while stack:
        cur = stack.pop()
        if isinstance(cur, list):
            mx = max(mx, len(cur))
            stack += cur
    return mx
```

---

```
In [6]:  longest([1,2,3])
Out[6]:  3

In [7]:  longest([[[1,2,3]]]) 
Out[7]:  3

In [8]:  longest([[], [3,[4,5],[2,3,4,5,3,3], [7], 5, [1,2,3], [3,4]], [1,2,3,4,5]])
Out[8]:  7
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [toolz library](https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz/), this can be achieved like this:

```
from toolz.curried import count

def longest(your_list): 
    return max(map(count, your_list))
```

One caveat: This doesn't work if  `your_list` contains non-iterables.

Answer (score -1):

Needs only one line:

```
max([len(i) for i in lst)])
```

When `lst` is a list of lists.

Comment: The result for  [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9]] should be 4. Your method would return 3. Also it's clear from the question that the lists can be nested more deeply.