# Maximum length list from list of lists using max with key

Tags: python, max

I would like to improve my understanding regarding the `key` argument of the builtin `max` function. Please consider the following example:

I have a list of lists, and I want to find the one with the biggest length.
I can write the straight forward solution:

```
maximum = 0
for l in lists:
   maximum = max(maximum, len(l))
```

However I would prefer to avoid an explicit for loop using the `key` argument of `max`. As I understand it, the key will apply its argument to each element in the input and then compare those outputs. So this should work:

```
maximum = max(lists, key=len)
```

I believe it should work because according to my (apparently false) understanding the above statement would be equivalent to applying length to each element and then invoking `max`:

```
max([len(l) for l in text_tokenized])
```

What am I missing?

Comment: have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902558/finding-the-longest-list-in-a-list-of-lists-in-python ?

Comment: It returns the list itself not the length. If you want to get the length use: `maximum = len(max(lists, key=len))`

Comment: Are you looking for `max(map(len, lists))`

Comment: What's the problem with your solution? It seems fine to me. Are you just asking if your thinking is correct? In which case: yes, it is. But you should really ask a tangible question with, if appropriate, a [mcve].

Comment: I am indeed trying to find out what I am missing from how max works, not how to solve the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe it should work because according to my (apparently false) understanding the above statement would be equivalent to applying length to each element and then invoking `max`:

No, The code

```
maximum = max(lists, key=len)
```

Means, find an "element" from `lists` which having maximum value of `len(element)`

Whereas, what you intended to find value of `len(element)`. one line quvilent of your code:

```
maximum = 0
for l in lists:
   maximum = max(maximum, len(l))
```

would be

```
max(map(len, lists))
```

or may be using `len(max(lists, key=len))`