# Find longest string in a list

Tags: python, list

I need to write a code where a function takes in a list and then returns the longest string from that list.

So far I have:

```
def longestword(alist):     
    a = 0     
    answer = '' 
    for i in alist:         
        x = i     
    if x > a:         
        a = x         
        answer = x     
    elif i == a:         
        if i not in alist:             
            answer = answer + ' ' + i     
    return answer
```

The example I have is `longestword([11.22,"hello",20000,"Thanksgiving!",True])`
which is supposed to return `'Thanksgiving!'` but my function always returns `True`.

Comment: Please us a descriptive title. Otherwise you have predjudiced most users against your question before they even open it!

Comment: My apologies for asking it the wrong way the first time everybody! I'm brand new to this site!

Comment: The thing with this list is that it's not homogeneous; if you're defining length in terms of value then 20000 would be the "longest"; if you're trying to do it based on character count then each element would have to be a string.

Comment: I see what your saying, the question asks that i return the longest string. not in terms of numbers.

Comment: So, are you ignoring numbers in your list outright or turning them into strings?

Comment: i would assume turning them in to strings. All i know is that the question i have in front of me says that with the list i gave in the question that Thanksgiving! should be returned from it. So if i can get some help at least doing that then it would be great

Comment: If you're turning it all to strings, that's not too tough - but at this point it becomes a duplicate [of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/873327/1079354), so I'd encourage you to check it out.

Comment: i don't believe that i'm turning them to strings. I just need to return whatever value in the list has the most index positions. Like "11.22" has 5 and "hello" has 5 and "Thanksgiving!" has 13. I just need to return the value that has the most index positions.

Comment: Those are not called "index positions", they're called characters.  Except that 11.22 does not have five characters, because it's not a string -- it doesn't have *any* characters.  If you want, you can get the string representation of that number -- "11.22", which does have five characters; that's what people are referring to when they say "turning the items into strings".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python's most efficient way to choose longest string in list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873327/pythons-most-efficient-way-to-choose-longest-string-in-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, this always assigns `x` to the very last value in the list, which in your example is `True`.

```
for i in alist:         
    x = i
```

And you should try not to access a loop value outside of the loop because, again, it's the last value of the thing you looped over, so `True`

```
elif i == a:
```

The key to solving the problem is to pick out which values are strings ([using `isinstance()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843173/how-to-check-if-type-of-a-variable-is-string#4843178)) and tracking the longest length ones (using the `len()` function)

```
def longeststring(lst):
  longest = ""
  for x in lst:
    if isinstance(x, str) and len(x) > len(longest):
      longest = x
  return longest
```

Do be mindful of equal length strings. I don't know the requirements of your assignment.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to keep the for loops to a minimum; here's how I find the longest string in a list:

```
listo = ["long     word 1  ",       " super OMG long    worrdddddddddddddddddddddd", "shortword" ]

lenList = []
for x in listo:
    lenList.append(len(x))
length = max(lenList)

print("Longest string is: {} at {} characters.".format(listo[lenList.index(length)] , length))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use...

```py
str_list = [x for x in alist if isinstance(x, str)]

longestword = sorted(str_list, key=len, reverse=True)[0]
```

Using a list comprehension, create `new_list` by iterating the elements of your original list and retaining only the strings with.

And then your list will be sorted by the `sorted()` function.

Applying the `key=len` argument, your list will be sorted by the length of the list element using the built-in-function `len()`.

And with the `reverse=True` argument, your list will be returned sorted in descending order, i.e. longest first.

Then you select index `[0]` of the sorted list which in this case, is the longest string.

To complete then:

```py
def longestword(alist):

    str_list = [x for x in alist if isinstance(x, str)]

    longestword = sorted(str_list, key=len, reverse=True)[0]

    return longestword
```

As Gavin rightly points out below, the sorting could be achieved without having to pass the `reverse=True` argument by returning the last element in the list with `[-1]`, i.e.:

```py
longestword = sorted(str_list, key=len)[-1]
```

Comment: Looks good! However, from the problem as specified doesn't seem you can guarantee that all elements of the list are strings. Maybe filter the list for strings first, a slight simplification could be to edit the sorted call using `sorted(tokens, key=len)[-1]` too.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Unfortunately it was asked to find only the strings, not other kind of data (see the accepted answer that handles it)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Gavin! I will also add your modification.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
def longest_string(some_list):
    only_str = [s for s in some_list if isinstance(s, str)]
    return max(only_str, key=len)
```

This method will create a list of strings named only_str. Then it will return the max length string using max() function.

When we run the longest_string() method with the example provided in the question:

```
some_list = [11.22,"hello",20000,"Thanksgiving!",True]
longest_string(some_list)
```

The output is: **'Thanksgiving!'**

Hope this solves this problem!!