# Check max length of array element in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check the max length of array elements. Although I can do it with simple code, is there another smart way to implement this in Python 3?

```
a = [[1,2], [1], [2,2,3,3], [2,2]]
max_len = 0
for d in a:
    max_len = len(d) if len(d) > max_len else max_len
print(max_len)
```

Comment: `max(len(x) for x in a)` or even shorter: `max(map(len,a))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python's most efficient way to choose longest string in list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873327/pythons-most-efficient-way-to-choose-longest-string-in-list)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
max_len = max([len(i) for i in a])
print(max_len)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the inbuilt max function:

```
>>> a = [[1,2], [1], [2,2,3,3], [2,2]]
>>> len(max(a, key=len))
4
```