# How can I check what is the biggest string in a list?

Tags: python

I want to check what is the biggest string in a list

Is there any function for this?
for example:

```py
lis = ['rafa', 'now', 'lucky']
```

And it returns 'lucky' or 5

Comment: `print(max(lis, key=lambda x: len(x)))` would do

Comment: `max(len(x) for x in lis]`

Comment: I did this:
```python
   a = '' 
    for i in table_head:
        if i > a:
            a = i
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: @rafa_rrayes Please [edit] the question. Comments aren't great for posting code.

Comment: @rafa_rrayes what have you tried so far / what are you having problems with?

Comment: @ZdaR `len` is already a function, so you can remove the lambda: `print(max(lis, key=len))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 max(lis, key=len)
```

output:

```
'lucky'
```

answered by [Paolo Bergantino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16417/paolo-bergantino) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873327/pythons-most-efficient-way-to-choose-longest-string-in-list)