# How to Find the Length of max itam in List? python

Tags: python, list

in my list I want the function to return only the maximum values within the list

```
my_list = ["and", "the", "plus", "from", "i" , "09"]
```

How can I get the output to be the maximum values ("plus", "from")
I did something like that, and I could not continue ...

```
my_list = ["and", "the", "plus", "from", "i" , "09"]
list1 = str(my_list)
list2 = list1.split(',')

for i in list2:
    if len(i) == max(len(i)):
        print(i)
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python's most efficient way to choose longest string in list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873327/pythons-most-efficient-way-to-choose-longest-string-in-list)

Comment: Why do you stringify the list and then split it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? Your description does not match what the code does *at all*. Why do you construct ``list2`` from the *string representation* of ``my_list`` (meaning that it has items like ``'["and"'``)? What do you think ``len(i) == max(len(i))`` does?

Answer (score 0):

```
def myFunction(words: list):
    output = []
    for word in sorted(words, key=len, reverse=True):
        maxLen = len(sorted(words, key=len, reverse=True)[0])
        if(len(word) < maxLen):
            break
        output.append(word)
    return {
        "words": output,
        "length": maxLen
    }
```

It takes the `words` list and sorts it from greatest to least length, then sets the `maxLen` variable to the length of the first thing in that list. Then, it looks to see if the length of the word the `for` loop is less than `maxLen`, and if it is, it stops the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get the lenght of longest string in list, you can use the shorhand version foor lop like `max([len(item) for item in my_list])`. but as far as I understood you would like to get the the string even if there are strings with same length you can try this:

```
def longest_items(my_list):
    max_len = 0
    items = []
    for item in my_list:
        if len(item) > max_len:
            max_len = len(item)
            items.clear()
            items.append(item)
        elif len(item) == max_len:
            items.append(item)
    return tuple(items)
```

This function will return longest string or strings in a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly use some list comprehension:

```py
>>> my_list = ["and", "the", "plus", "from", "i" , "09"]
>>> lengths = [len(s) for s in my_list]
>>> max_lengths = [s for s in my_list if len(s) == max(lengths)]
>>> max_lengths
["plus", "from"]
```

The list in `lengths` stores the length of each string in `my_list`. Then, by using the `max()` function, we can quickly obtaining the maximum value in `lengths`, which corresponds to the maximum length of a string. Finally, we re-iterate over `my_list` and compare each string value to `max(lengths)`, checking if each string is the maximum length.

Note that, if desired, this all can be condensed into one list comprehension:

```py
>>> max_lengths = [i for i in my_list if len(i) == max([len(s) for s in my_list])]
>>> max_lengths
["plus", "from"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    my_list = ["and", "the", "plus", "from", "i", "09"]
    
    length = 0
    arr = []
    for i in my_list:
        if len(i) > length:
            length = len(i)
            arr = []
        if len(i) == length:
            arr.append(i)
            length = len(i)
    
    print(arr)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
list2 = list1.split(',')
```

split is a string function, it turns a string into a list. Like `"john, tim, and paul"` would turn into `["john", " tim", " and paul"]`

`max` takes an iterator and returns the highest value. you did `max(len(i))` ... len(i) is just going to return an integer, so you did `max(6)`. Instead, you want to make a list of the lengths. `max([len(x) for x in list1])` would give you the length of the longest item in list1.